# How can I change targetsdk to 17 in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I change my application's target sdk from api 10 to api 17 in android studio ? my application is not receiving data from internet in 4.1 version of android mobile but working fine with 2.3.3

This is my mainifest.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.national.nhl"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.national.nhl.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.national.nhl.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.national.nhl.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: your question should be what you want to achieve ? don't change your question context in comments. Update your question with what you want to achieve and where are you facing the issue ? Include the code for fetching the data.

Comment: You are repeating that "I change this to 17 but still not working".
targetSdkVersion 17 changes the target in AS. It doesn't mean that your app has to work. Check your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now in the latest Android studio version `android:targetSdkVersion` is no more defined in manifest file. Use build.gradle under your application folder to change.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"


defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question? Do you want to change target sdk version to 17? Then just change

```
android:targetSdkVersion="10"
```

to

```
android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

and save your changed manifest.

Comment: i change this to 17 but it still not working i use jsoup html parsing it get all data in htc desire s but not getting data in samsung galaxy s3 what should i do???

Comment: You have to change this setting in your `build.gradle` file otherwise the `defaultConfig` will override the settings in your Manifest. Look at my answer above.

Comment: i change build.gradle defaultConfig targetsdkVersion to 17 but still it is not getting data from internet

Comment: please look at your question!

Answer (score 0):

Look into your `build.gradle` file of your app, there you find the defaultConfig  where you can change the targetSDK to 17:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 17
}
```

Comment: Clean your build ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build